# Add link to SiteOrigin Image widget's title

Tags: wordpress, siteorigin

On one of the websites for our customer, there's a SiteOrigin WordPress plugin installed.

One of the widgets that come with this plugin is SiteOrigin Image widget. There you could add a destination URL to the main image but it is not applied on the title text so basically, only the image leads works as a link which is annoying for our client.

See here, the "How" is not a link:

[image]

I've tried to find a way to do this the SiteOrigin way but the only thing I found was [this outdated thread](https://siteorigin.com/thread/siteorigin-image-destination-url/).

Is there an easy and elegant way to achieve it without using custom javascript or editing plugin's widget code (or replicating the widget)?